# $compile return html in object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so im calling a html template and want to bind the data with angular, so i get the data to bind, i get the html, when i try to compile it will return all the html binded but in (i think) object, what can i do to make it html.

This is the code

```
$.get("file.html", function(partial){

        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.data = result;

        var el = angular.element(partial);

        var compiled = $compile(el)(scope);
        var finalHtml = el[0];


        $timeout(function(){
            var calendar = window.open();
            calendar.document.write(finalHtml);
            calendar.focus();
            calendar.print();
        });
    });
```

I already try .html .toString String() nothing worked

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to load a template? Use angular methods if you want to use angular. Where is this code from? $compile is only ever needed in own directives.

Comment: Use $templateRequester

Comment: @ Kevin Dreßler thank you for your reply, the result is just html but behave like object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `compiled` variable is an angular jQuery or jqlite element that can be inserted into your document.  If you want to get the html for it, you can use use the `outerHTML` attribute on the underlying node (you get the underlying node by grabbing the first array element `compiled[0]`) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

```
var compiled = $compile(el)(scope);
// scope.$digest() // only call if not within an angular $digest already
$timeout(function() {
  var finalHtml = compiled[0].outerHTML;
  ...
}
```

According to the documentation "After linking the view is not updated until after a call to $digest which typically is done by Angular automatically." so you either have to manually call `scope.$digest()` or actually use one the angular API to do the request using either `$http` or preferably using `$templateRequest` like @ThinkingMedia suggested.  After the angular $digest has run, then you can access the updated view.

I created a plunker here that shows how it all works properly using just the AngularJS api: http://plnkr.co/edit/rFcfgB3FWhsfyySfr0rU?p=preview

I also changed how the popup is opened a bit to deal with the security implication of doing popups.

Comment: @JoãoReis I updated my answer to correct my mistake, use ThinkingMedia's suggestion, and provide a working example